# Installing openCV 3 in Raspian Jessie Pixel

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, opencv3.0, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to install OpenCV 3 in the raspian Jessie Pixel according to the method given on the following link : http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/ but when i am trying "make -j4" command  raspian OS got stuck and it made the processor speed so slow. The monitor screen went black and after certain time it comes back but still it will be stuck. Please help me in fixing this problem. 
Is there any other way that i can try for installing openCV 3.

Comment: Did you see under the command in the guide it says 1.5 hours? How long were you waiting?

Comment: Also, when you compile it (`make -j4`), it is probably taking up 100% of every core, which is causing everything else to slow down.